# Differences between merge and match functions in R

Tags: r

I everybody I remove my last post to make a reproducible exmaple of my problem. I am working with the next to data frames `a1` (dput structure):

```
structure(list(r04_numero_operacion = c("0050475725", "0050490602", 
"0050491033", "0050496386", "0050518985", "0050630090", "0050631615", 
"0060235906", "0060238732", "0060241333", "0060244391", "0060245813", 
"0060260056", "0060266356", "0800041441", "0800054041", "0800055382", 
"0800058554", "2020200062", "2020200073", "CAR1010001706000", 
"CAR1010001795000", "CAR1010001803000", "CAR1010001871000", "CAR1010001962000", 
"CAR1010002002000", "CAR1010002120000", "CAR1010002189000", "CAR1010002215000", 
"CAR1010002250000"), perdida3 = c(523.12, 265.43, 8371.66, 5242.13, 
4960.51, 8473.27, 3743.45, 1283.32, 2229.25, 8001.27, 8653.94, 
3670.13, 4536.02, 8216.55, 2481.36, 288.94, 1637.28, 4566.89, 
1573.63, 11217.92, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9633.9, 0), Saldo = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 288.94, 1637.28, 4566.89, 
1, 1, 481.59, 299.52, 258.13, 603.84, 231.61, 631.68, 220.6, 
210.54, 1, 1224.44), Bvencida = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 603.84, 0, 631.68, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Cvencida = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1224.44), 
    Dvencida = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), vencida = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 288.94, 1637.28, 
    4566.89, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 603.84, 0, 631.68, 0, 0, 1, 1224.44
    ), V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("r04_numero_operacion", 
"perdida3", "Saldo", "Bvencida", "Cvencida", "Dvencida", "vencida", 
"V1"), codepage = 1252L, row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

And `a2` data frame (dput structure):

```
structure(list(r04_numero_operacion = c("0050475725", "0050490602", 
"0050491033", "0050496386", "0050518985", "0050630090", "0050631615", 
"0060235906", "0060238732", "0060241333", "0060244391", "0060245813", 
"0060260056", "0060266356", "0800041441", "0800054041", "0800055382", 
"0800058554", "2020200073", "CAR1010002002000", "CAR1010002189000", 
"CAR1010002215000", "CAR1010002250000", "CAR1010002264000", "CAR1010002297000", 
"CAR1010002401000", "CAR1010002412000", "CAR1010002436000", "CAR1010002529000", 
"CAR1010002709000"), perdida3 = c(523.12, 265.43, 8371.66, 5242.13, 
4960.51, 8473.27, 3743.45, 1283.32, 2229.25, 8001.27, 8653.94, 
3670.13, 4536.02, 8216.55, 2481.36, 288.94, 1637.28, 4566.89, 
11217.92, 0, 0, 9633.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Saldo = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 288.94, 1637.28, 4566.89, 
1, 317.72, 210.54, 1, 868.93, 242.91, 298.78, 120.63, 255.01, 
357.68, 284.08, 308.83), Bvencida = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 317.72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Cvencida = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 868.93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Dvencida = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), vencida = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 288.94, 1637.28, 4566.89, 1, 317.72, 0, 
1, 868.93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2)), .Names = c("r04_numero_operacion", "perdida3", "Saldo", 
"Bvencida", "Cvencida", "Dvencida", "vencida", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
30L))
```

My problem is when I use `merge()` and `match()` functions. `merge()` is more functional than `match()` related to add new variables by common one but when I use `merge()` I don't get the same result as `match()`. First I used `merge()` with `a2` and `a1` to create `DF` with the next code:

```
DF=merge(a2,a1,all.x=TRUE)
```

It added `V1` variable from `a1` to `DF` and I got this summary for `DF$V1`:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  1       1       1       1       1       1       9
```

After I create a copy of `a2` named `DF` and I made a match with `r04_numero_operacion` using this code to add `V1` variable from `a1` to `a2`:

```
a2$V1<-a1[match(a2$r04_numero_operacion,a1$r04_numero_operacion),"V1"]
```

It added `` `V1 `` to `DF` but the result is different to the `merge()` way. I got this summary for `DF$V1` in `match()` solution:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  1       1       1       1       1       1       7
```

My problem is I want to make the same I made with `match()` but using `merge()` function due to this function is more poweful than `match()`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In using `match(a2$r04_numero_operacion,a1$r04_numero_operacion)` the a2$r04_numero_operacion values gets matched the coresponding column in a1 while in using `merge(a2,a1,all.x=TRUE)` the a1 all the matching columns get matched to the matching column names in a2. If you only match on the first column, the NA counts match up:

```
summary( merge(a2,a1,by=1,all.x=TRUE)$V1 )
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      1       1       1       1       1       1       7
```

Comment: Thanks @DWin but the problem is that I only want to keep the original variables from `a2` and when I add `by` in  `merge` I got more variables. Is it possible to keep only variable from `a2`. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep just one variable, you can exclude the others before the merge: `merge(a2,a1[,c(1,8)],all.x=T,by=1)`

Comment: Of course. Just pass in the one column to be matched and added V1-column: `merge(a2, a1[ c("04_numero_operacion", "V1")], by=1,all.x=TRUE)`  ...  or "what he said".

Comment: Interesting and by default there is anyway in merge to keep variables from `a1` instead of write `a1[ c("04_numero_operacion", "V1")]`?? @DWin

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can keep any of them you want. You are the one that asked that they be dropped.

Comment: It is strange but is a complex problem I am trying to solve but your help was gold, you are awesome @DWin maybe do you have twitter or any place where I can request your help if it is necessary?

Comment: Dear @DWin it is possible that after merge(a2,a1) I could get in the merged data frame V variables in this case `V1` and `V2` ordered for example first `V1` and after `V2`

Comment: It's very easy to change the order of columns. There was even that exact question answered within the last day or two.

Comment: Actually it was the question about selection of columns but the principle is the same... use a numeric vector in `[,]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757554/r-data-frame-extracting-non-sequential-columns-and-creating-new-sub-data-frames