# R data frame extracting non-sequential columns and creating new sub data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a data frame consisting of 25 columns and 30,000 rows. I want to create sub-data frames that contain all rows but only certain columns that are in non-sequential order. As an example, a sub data frame containing columns 1, 12, 15, and 25.

I have been playing around with lapply but I dont know how to create the sub data frames with columns that are in non-sequential order.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `?"Extract"`. Suppose `df` is your data.frame, then `df[,c(1,12,15,25)]` should give the result you want.

Comment: Thank you! I come from a python background and I am still learning the built-in R functions.

Answer (score 1):

Information from `data.frame`s can be extracted by using the indices of a `data.frame`'s rows, columns, or both.

The general form is of:

```
dataset[rows_wanted, cols_wanted]
```

Omitting one of those returns all of what was omitted. For example, `dataset[c(1, 2, 3), ]` would return rows one through three, and all the columns.

Thus, for your problem, you can simply do:

```
dataset[, c(1, 2, 12, 25)]
```